# Sequelize - Abstracted query to select all records older than 5 minutes using MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm struggling to write an abstracted query using sequelize that will identify a record older than 5 minutes using the "updatedAt" column. My query reads as follows:

```
const Jts = await models.Jts.findOne({
    where: {
        publish: true,
        retry: {
            [Op.lte]: 3
        },
        updatedAt: {
            [Op.lte]: [sequelize.fn("(NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)")]
        }
    },
    include: ["OrgSetEntries"],
    paranoid: false,
    order: [
        ["effectiveDate", "ASC"],
        ["updatedAt", "ASC"]
    ]
});
```

I have tried a few syntaxes but am struggling. The generated query always produces "Invalid Date" string eg:

```
... updatedAt` &lt;= 'Invalid date';
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Sequelize.literal("NOW() - (INTERVAL '5 MINUTE')")` to do get the data rows which updated at 5 minutes ago.

E.g.

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import Sequelize, { Model, DataTypes, Op } from 'sequelize';

class Jts extends Model {}
Jts.init(
  {
    publish: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    retry: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'jts' },
);

(async function test() {
  try {
    // create tables
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    let date1 = new Date();
    date1.setHours(date1.getHours() - 1);
    await Jts.bulkCreate([
      { publish: false, retry: 2 },
      { publish: false, retry: 5 },
      { publish: true, retry: 2, updatedAt: date1 },
      { publish: true, retry: 1, updatedAt: new Date() },
    ]);
    // test
    const result = await Jts.findOne({
      where: {
        publish: true,
        retry: {
          [Op.lte]: 3,
        },
        updatedAt: {
          [Op.lte]: Sequelize.literal("NOW() - (INTERVAL '5 MINUTE')"),
        },
      },
      raw: true,
    });
    console.log('result:', result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

The execution result:

```sh
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "jts" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "jts" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "jts" ("id"   SERIAL , "publish" BOOLEAN, "retry" INTEGER, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'jts' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "jts" ("id","publish","retry","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,false,2,NULL),(DEFAULT,false,5,NULL),(DEFAULT,true,2,'2020-04-16 12:50:43.458 +00:00'),(DEFAULT,true,1,'2020-04-16 13:50:43.458 +00:00') RETURNING *;
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "publish", "retry", "updatedAt" FROM "jts" AS "jts" WHERE "jts"."publish" = true AND "jts"."retry" <= 3 AND "jts"."updatedAt" <= NOW() - (INTERVAL '5 MINUTE') LIMIT 1;
result: { id: 3,
  publish: true,
  retry: 2,
  updatedAt: 2020-04-16T12:50:43.458Z }
```

Check the database:

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "jts";
 id | publish | retry |         updatedAt
----+---------+-------+----------------------------
  1 | f       |     2 |
  2 | f       |     5 |
  3 | t       |     2 | 2020-04-16 12:50:43.458+00
  4 | t       |     1 | 2020-04-16 13:50:43.458+00
(4 rows)
```

The data row which `id = 3` updated at one hour ago is we want to get.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the great answer! I had to tweak my version, perhaps a difference in MySQL versions(?) Mine reads

    [Op.lte]: Sequelize.literal("DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)")

Comment: @prime sorry. I use PostgreSQL, so maybe there is a little difference with MySQL

Comment: If it's to get records older than 5 min shouldnt the query be 
[Op.gte]: Sequelize.literal("DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)") 
instead of  
[Op.lte]: Sequelize.literal("DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)")

I'm just curious pls anyone can enlighten me